# How to ensure completion of a async operation before continuing with execution

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am building an iOS app and some part of its code relies on the success/failure value returned from a particular task.This tasks involves callbacks from a library. I want the return value from this task to be returned only after the callback has returned either success/failure. But since I wrote a sequential code the return value is returned even before the callback returns a success/failure.

I looked into using modal view controllers and from what I understand I can make the task execute from this view controller and then return the code back.

But this also doesn't suit my requirements as when the code which initiates the callback sequence is executed I don't want a new view controller to be displayed. Although there is a certain callback which requires me to prompt the user for information. I do this in a popover and I considered making the view controller within the popover modal. But then the callbacks will still be part of the main thread and I won't receive them when my popover is presented modally(?).

With my current understanding of these concepts I don't know how to proceed. Is there some way to do this in iOS?

**EDIT:**
The code does something like this

```
//In CustomTableViewController

-(void) someFunc
{
   ENUM_NAME code = [TaskController startTheTask:args];
   if(code == SUCCEEDED)
   {
      //Do Something
   }
   if(code == FAILED)
   {
      //Do Something Else
   }
}

//In TaskController

-(ENUM_NAME) startTheTask:args
{
   startWorkflow(args); //This function registers callback function with the library. 
   return finalCode; //This is returned even before it is set to SUCCEEDED/FAILED
}

-(void) onCallback:params
{
    MSG_TYPE msg = [params getMsg];

    if(msg == TASK_FAILED)
       finalCode = FAILED;
    if(msg == TASK_SUCCEEDED)
       finalCode = SUCCEEDED;
    if(msg == TASK_SHOW_PROMPT)
    {  
       [PopOverController showPopOver];
    }
}

-(void) onUserInfoAdded
{
    //This is called when Confirm is clicked in the popover
    continueWorkflow(params); //asks for the next callback to happen
}

-(void) onCancleClicked
{
    //This is called when Popover is dismissed without entering Info
    cancleWorkflow(params); //asks for result of the workflow through callback
}
```

Comment: You could use delegate methods that will be trigged once your async method is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCD. For example:

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{           
         //put one process here
         dispatch_group_leave(group);  //when done
    });

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{           
         //put another process here
         dispatch_group_leave(group); //when done
    });

    // All updates finished
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         // add last steps here after all processess are finished
    });

    dispatch_release(group);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a semaphore to delay the execution until a block returns:

```
__block dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
__block NSData *dataFromTheBlock = nil;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // block implementation
    // dataFromTheBlock = some data;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
});
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With respect to the code i posted, should all the functions in `TaskController` be part of this block? Is there some other way to get callbacks without the `onCallback` function being the part of this block?

Comment: It is not mandatory to have a block. The point is that you ca block the current thread with `dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` and continue the execution when you call `dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);`. Of course, these 2 calls cannot be on the same thread, because it would block that thread indefinitely.

Comment: There's no point in blocking a thread to obtain the result from an asynchronous task and continue the program after the result is eventually available. Actually, it's a code smell. You may take a look at julie's answer which is one reasonable approach.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I agree, that it is not very healthy to block the main thread, but what happens if for example you have to return something in a method, and that something comes from a block? You would somehow have to wait and block the thread until that block is executed, right? And for what OP asked "How to ensure completion of a async operation before continuing with execution" I believe it is a good answer for the "before continuing execution" part. However, Julies answer showed me a few things I didn't know about, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Levi In order to obtain the *eventual* result of an asynchronous method and continue with the program, you define a "continuation". A "continuation" can be a Block which will be defined by the *call-site* and basically contains the code to execute *when* the task is finished. When the task finished, it *calls* this block and passes its result as a parameter to the Block. Thus, the Block defines *how* to continue with the program *when* the result is available. This is a common asynchronous pattern, and completely avoids to block threads.