# How to pause a main thread until a block is finished Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform

I have a problem.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    if (image == nil){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Try again !" message:@"Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
    }else{
        NSData *fileData;
        NSString *fileName;
        NSString *fileType;
        fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        fileName = @"profilePic.png";
        fileType = @"Image";
        PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:fileData];
        [file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!"
                                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please try sending your message again. %@",error.userInfo]
                                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
            }else{
                [[PFUser currentUser]setObject:file forKey:@"profilePic"];
                [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeed, NSError* error){
                    if (!error) {
                        NSLog(@"New profile pic loaded.");
                        [self.activity stopAnimating];
                        [self.reloadPicBtn setHidden:NO];
                    }else{
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Try again !" message:@"Please try again. Failed to load your new profile pic :(" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                        [alert show];

                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
}];

}
```

Well, `reloadPicBtn` is shown, but if I call a function which reloads a picture, It fails. And when I try to understand WTF is going on using `NSLog` it logs out a string. So code has been executed. But there is no result on screen. The function is the same which is called in `viewDidLoad`. But it works when it is called from `viewDidLoad`. And when it is called again there is no result.

That reload function:

```
- (void) loadProfilePic{
PFQuery* query = [PFUser query];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId block:^(PFObject* object, NSError* error){
    if(!error){
        PFFile* imageFile = object[@"profilePic"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData* data, NSError* error){
            if (!error) {
                self.activity.hidden = NO;
                [self.activity startAnimating];
                self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                NSLog(@"Profile pic shown");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Error 2: %@",error);
            }
        }];

    }else{
        self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile@2.png"];
        NSLog(@"Fail 1 : %@",error);
    }
}];
}
```

Please help me.

It prints out profile pic shown. But it doesn't even use network to download an image.

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125912/how-to-ensure-completion-of-a-async-operation-before-continuing-with-execution/23126004#23126004

Comment: Why is this tagged `parse.com`?

Comment: I don't think so you can block main thread but you can show loading( or use sleep function it will block main thread)

Comment: You can block the main thread quite easily. The problem is that your customers are going to hate you for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is from your description (I don't know what you mean by "it fails"or it works) because I can't visualize the functional goal.  And I'm also not sure I can see the cause of *any* problem from a read through of the code.  But I do know this: (a) you don't want to pause the main thread, and (b) code reading headaches go away -- and sometime bugs disappear, too -- when code is written to to **separate concerns**.  I could show you how to do that, if you like, but it doesn't guarantee a fix.